# Hibernate throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on some native queries returning POJOs with Pageable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Java, Spring, Hibernate (& jhipster & openapi) and an Oracle database in a project and a couple of my repository findAll() methods throw an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0" exception when calling them with a Pageable argument. (However, other classes using the same pattern do not). Also, calling a similar method without a Pageable argument does not throw an exception.

Here is an example of one that throws this exception:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GrefFacts.findAllSasVariables",
    query = "SELECT gf.fact_id                  AS factid," +
            "        gf.script_variable_nm      AS sasname," +
            "        upper(gf.script_variable_nm)," +
            "        gf.script_variable_desc    AS sasdesc," +
            "        gf.data_type_lcd           AS sasdatatype," +
            "        gf.bt_answer_msk           AS bitposmask," +
            "        gf.metadata_status_lcd     AS sasstatus," +
            "        gf.answer_id               AS answerid," +
            "        nus.new_script_variable_nm AS saspname," +
            "        upper(nus.new_script_variable_nm)," +
            "        nus.script_variable_desc   AS saspdesc," +
            "        script_note_str            AS saspnote," +
            "        (SELECT COUNT(sf.cat_id)" +
            "           FROM sdde_facts sf" +
            "          WHERE gf.fact_id = sf.fact_id" +
            "        )                          AS saslinkedcvarcount" +
            "   FROM gref_facts            gf" +
            "   LEFT JOIN gref_not_used_scripts nus" +
            "     ON gf.script_variable_nm = nus.script_variable_nm" +
            "  ORDER BY upper(gf.script_variable_nm) ASC," +
            "           upper(nus.new_script_variable_nm) ASC",
    resultSetMapping = "SasVariableMapping"
)

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GrefFacts.findAllSasVariables.count",
    query = "SELECT count(gf.fact_id)" +
            "   FROM gref_facts            gf" +
            "   LEFT JOIN gref_not_used_scripts nus" +
            "     ON gf.script_variable_nm = nus.script_variable_nm"
)

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "SasVariableMapping",
    classes=@ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = com.epsilon.metadater.domain.SasVariable.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "factId", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasName",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasDesc",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasDataType",type = Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "bitPosMask",type = Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasStatus",type = Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "answerId", type = Long.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasPName",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasPDesc",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasPNote",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "sasLinkedCvarCount",type = Integer.class)
        }
))

@Table( ... )
public class GrefFacts implements Serializable { ... }
```

```java
@Repository
public interface GrefFactsRepository extends JpaRepository<GrefFacts, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<GrefFacts>
{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<SasVariable> findAllSasVariables();
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    Page<SasVariable> findAllSasVariables(Pageable pageable);
}
```

```java
public class SasVariablesApiDelegateImpl implements SasVariablesApiDelegate
{
    private final GrefFactsRepository grefFactsRepository;
    public ResponseEntity<List<SasVariable>> getSasVariables(Pageable pageable, Boolean unpaged)
    {
        Page<SasVariable> page = grefFactsRepository.findAllSasVariables(pageable); // <-- Exception thrown here
    }
}
```

and this is the Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.findAllSasVariables(Unknown Source)
        at com.epsilon.metadater.web.api.SasVariablesApiDelegateImpl.getSasVariables(SasVariablesApiDelegateImpl.java:68)
        at com.epsilon.metadater.web.api.SasVariablesApi.getSasVariables(SasVariablesApi.java:51)
        at com.epsilon.metadater.web.api.SasVariablesApi$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$923ad51a.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
        at com.epsilon.metadater.web.api.SasVariablesApiController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa4a950a.getSasVariables(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at com.epsilon.metadater.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:37)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:908)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1003)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.doCreateCountQuery(NamedQuery.java:190)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.doCreateCountQuery(NamedQuery.java:43)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createCountQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:253)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.count(JpaQueryExecution.java:183)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.lambda$doExecute$0(JpaQueryExecution.java:178)
        at org.springframework.data.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:62)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:51)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:177)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.resultClassChecking(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:965)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:924)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:902)
        ... 170 common frames omitted
```

Update I initallialy had these versions:

```
<java.version>11</java.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.4.7</spring-boot.version>
<hibernate.version>5.4.32.Final</hibernate.version>
```

and have since updated to the latest versions and it still happens:

```
<spring-boot.version>2.6.2</spring-boot.version>
<hibernate.version>5.6.2.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Here is an example of a native query that works (does NOT throw an Exception) using the same Entity class. However it only returns a few rows, much less than a page:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GrefFacts.findCvarLinksBySas",
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT\n"+
        "    ( nvl(c.qvroot, ' ')\n"+
        "      || nvl(w.qvsufx, ' ') ) AS cvarName,\n"+
        "    sf.tk_bit               AS tkBit\n"+
        "FROM gref_facts gf,\n"+
        "     sdde_facts sf,\n"+
        "     sdd_c      c,\n"+
        "     sdd_w      w\n"+
        "WHERE gf.script_variable_nm = :sasName\n"+
        "  AND gf.fact_id = sf.fact_id\n"+
        "  AND sf.cat_id = c.catid\n"+
        "  AND c.catid = w.catid\n"+
        "  AND sf.tk_word = w.tkword\n"+
        "ORDER BY cvarname ASC, tkbit ASC",
    resultSetMapping = "CvarLinkMapping"
)

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GrefFacts.findCvarLinksBySas.count",
    query = "SELECT count(*)\n"+
            "  FROM (\n"+
            "SELECT DISTINCT\n"+
            "    (c.qvroot || w.qvsufx) AS cvarName,\n"+
            "    sf.tk_bit              AS tkBit\n"+
            "FROM gref_facts gf,\n"+
            "     sdde_facts sf,\n"+
            "     sdd_c      c,\n"+
            "     sdd_w      w\n"+
            "WHERE gf.script_variable_nm = :sasName\n"+
            "  AND gf.fact_id = sf.fact_id\n"+
            "  AND sf.cat_id = c.catid\n"+
            "  AND c.catid = w.catid\n"+
            "  AND sf.tk_word = w.tkword\n"+
            ")"
)

@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "CvarLinkMapping",
    classes=@ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = com.epsilon.metadater.domain.CvarLink.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "cvarName",type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "tkBit",type = Integer.class),
        }
))
```

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<CvarLink> findCvarLinksBySas(@Param("sasName") String sasName);

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    Page<CvarLink> findCvarLinksBySas(@Param("sasName") String sasName,
                                      Pageable pageable);
```

```
public class CvarLinksApiDelegateImpl implements CvarLinksApiDelegate
{
    private final GrefFactsRepository grefFactsRepository;

    public ResponseEntity<List<CvarLink>> getCvarLinks(String sasname,
                                                       Pageable pageable,
                                                       Boolean unpaged)
    {
            Page<CvarLink> page = grefFactsRepository.findCvarLinksBySas(sasname, pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the Hibernate version to your question?

Comment: I don't know why, but it hits the error dealing with your count query, which is why it works without paging. How does your count query work with the other queries that work with pageable?

Comment: The count query returns the correct count when I execute it using Oracle SQL Developer, as do the count queries for the other queries.

COUNT(GF.FACT_ID)
-----------------
            25487

Comment: I added an example of a query that does work

Comment: I've debugging this issue for hours and I found the reason, it's because the NamedNativeQuery for counting does not have resultSetMapping or resultClass then causing "queryReturns = namedQueryDefinition.getQueryReturns()" to be empty then leading to an error at final NativeSQLQueryReturn nativeSQLQueryReturn = queryReturns[0];
line 965 from AbstractSharedSessionContract class

Comment: I try to use resultClass/ResultSetMapping but I stuck again due to the namednativequery for count query is being created as java.lang.Long and won't accept other targets than Long, I am trying to find a way as resultClass/ResultSetMapping only accept Entities.
These issues are really annoying me, another thing I tried was using countQuery which also did not works having a silent exception where it could not find the named query for "count" or any name I give to the count

Answer (score 1):

You need to add resultSetMapping to your count query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GrefFacts.findAllSasVariables.count",
    resultSetMapping = "sasVariableCount",
    query = "SELECT count(gf.fact_id)" +
            "   FROM gref_facts            gf" +
            "   LEFT JOIN gref_not_used_scripts nus" +
            "     ON gf.script_variable_nm = nus.script_variable_nm")
```

Then add

```
@SqlResultSetMappings(value = {
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "sasVariableCount",
        columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "count", type = Long.class) }
    ),
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "SasVariableMapping",
        classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = com.epsilon.metadater.domain.SasVariable.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "factId", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasName",type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasDesc",type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasDataType",type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "bitPosMask",type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasStatus",type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "answerId", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasPName",type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasPDesc",type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasPNote",type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sasLinkedCvarCount",type = Integer.class)
                }
            )
        }
    )
})
```